# What kind of regression to use when there is multiple time series in both dependent and independent variables

Tags: regression, time-series, finance

I am trying to find a relationship between Return on Assets (RoA) and Stock price within a certain industry (e.g. Semiconductor). My dependent variable is stock price of various companies in this industry and my independent variable is RoA of each of the same companies. If there are 20 companies in this industry I have a 20 time series of each of these companies for both stock price and RoA.  The values for RoA are between 0% to 50% as they vary for same company as well as different companies. The big challenge is in stock price which has a range from \$1 to \$1000. I see in my time series that there are 3 or more values of stock price for a same RoA value (e.g., RoA - 20% and stock price is \$20 and \$200 and \$800. When I run a regression of these two variables I am unable to find any meaningful results.

I also tried regression by taking percentage change or simple difference but still no luck. Even if there isn't any relationship between RoA and stick price can someone help me on how I can find correlation between these type of variables which have multiple time series within them.